# Terminator fails to start in i686, DBus issue in Python

Tags: d-bus, 32bit, gnome-terminator

I have a fresh Arch install on a i686 system, running Terminator 1.91. The program is refusing to load, debugging gives me the output:

```
ConfigBase::__init__: Borg::__init__: Preparing borg state for ConfigBase
noclass::get_config_dir: Found config dir: /home/pradana/.config
ConfigBase::load: looking for config file: /home/pradana/.config/terminator/config
ConfigBase::load: config validated successfully
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing section: global_config
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing section: keybindings
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: cycle_prev
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: help
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: close_window
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: group_tab
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: resize_left
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: broadcast_all
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: rotate_ccw
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: move_tab_left
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: go_right
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: new_tab
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: resize_right
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: resize_down
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: toggle_zoom
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: scaled_zoom
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: zoom_in
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: paste
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: full_screen
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: prev_tab
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: split_vert
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: ungroup_all
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: broadcast_off
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: cycle_next
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: rotate_cw
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: insert_number
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: insert_padded
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: zoom_out
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: broadcast_group
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: go_prev
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: layout_launcher
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: close_term
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: new_terminator
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: ungroup_tab
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: go_left
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: copy
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: hide_window
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: edit_tab_title
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: go_down
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: reset
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: search
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: go_up
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: resize_up
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: next_tab
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: split_horiz
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: zoom_normal
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: move_tab_right
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: new_window
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: edit_window_title
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: group_all
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: go_next
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: edit_terminal_title
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: reset_clear
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing keybindings: toggle_scrollbar
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing section: profiles
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing profile: default
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing section: layouts
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing layouts: default
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing layouts: 3term
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: Processing section: plugins
Config::set_profile: Config::set_profile: Changing profile to default
Config::connect_gsetting_callbacks: GSetting connects for system changes
noclass::parse_options: OptionParse::parse_options: command line options: {'nodbus': None, 'classname': None, 'working_directory': None, 'select': None, 'fullscreen': None, 'layout': 'default', 'debug_classes': None, 'version': None, 'role': None, 'forcedicon': None, 'config': '/home/pradana/.config/terminator/config', 'profile': None, 'debug_methods': None, 'maximise': None, 'debug': 1, 'borderless': None, 'new_tab': None, 'hidden': None, 'dummy': None, 'execute': None, 'geometry': None, 'command': None, 'forcedtitle': None}
ConfigBase::load: ConfigBase::load: config already loaded
Config::set_profile: Config::set_profile: Changing profile to default
Config::connect_gsetting_callbacks: GSetting connects for system changes
ConfigBase::get_item: ConfigBase::get_item: dbus found in globals: True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/terminator", line 83, in <module>
    from terminatorlib import ipc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/terminatorlib/ipc.py", line 31, in <module>
    class DBusService(Borg, dbus.service.Object):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/terminatorlib/ipc.py", line 62, in DBusService
    @dbus.service.method(BUS_NAME, in_signature='a{ss}')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dbus/decorators.py", line 155, in method
    validate_interface_name(dbus_interface)
ValueError: Invalid interface or error name 'net.tenshu.Terminator2-0x21012a2c': contains invalid character '-'
```

It seems that there is something wrong is DBus. I am able to run Terminator by using

```
$ terminator -u
```

disaling DBus; however if I want to configure a shortcut in GNOME settings, it doesn't open it.